# ServiceChannel Object is more in memory dump of webapi

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, webapi

I have an webapi and in turns it calls many wcf services, over a period of time the w3p memory is growing and we have to restart the Apppool. After taking memory dump I could witness that there were more number of ServiceChannel objects are created over a period of time. What could be the reason for this ? I could see that whenever a wcfclient is created there is no Close() function called but instead Abort() is called. Is it the right way to handle the client ?

Comment: Correct approach would be to call Dispose(), not even calling Close() explicitly. Dispose() calls Close() internally. Wrap your calls inside a using statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Dispose` or `Close` as usual but that's not enough, because:

> The C# `using` statement results in a call to `Dispose()`. This is the same as `Close()`, which may throw exceptions when a network error occurs.

The recommended way to close WCF client can be found [here in this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/use-close-abort-release-wcf-client-resources).

Meanwhile, having large number of `ServiceChannel` in memory does not necessarily mean they directly connect to the memory leak issue. They could simply mean your application, at the time of the memory snapshot was taken, was busy doing WCF calls.

However, if you could find a `ServiceChannel` which is supposed to be disposed but still exists in memory, then it would be a good indication.